# what does this universal ctags error mean: Don't reuse the kind letter

Tags: swift, ctags, universal-ctags

Since universal-stags doesn't support swift out of the box, I added [this](https://akrabat.com/ctags-with-swift/) to my `~/.ctags.d/ctags.ctags`:

```
--langdef=Swift
--langmap=Swift:+.swift
--regex-swift=/(var|let)[ \t]+([^:=<]+).*$/\2/,variable/
--regex-swift=/func[ \t]+([^\(\)<]+)\([^\(\)]*\)/\1/,function/
--regex-swift=/class[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/,class/
--regex-swift=/struct[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/,struct/
--regex-swift=/protocol[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/,protocol/
```

But when I run the command

```
ctags . -R
```

I get this weird warning

```
ctags . -R
ctags: Warning: Don't reuse the kind letter `r' in a language Swift (old: "variable", new: "function")
ctags: Warning: Don't reuse the kind letter `r' in a language Swift (old: "variable", new: "class")
ctags: Warning: Don't reuse the kind letter `r' in a language Swift (old: "variable", new: "struct")
ctags: Warning: Don't reuse the kind letter `r' in a language Swift (old: "variable", new: "protocol")
```

and my `tags` file doesn't get updated.
Interestingly enough, if I run this command

```
ctags --languages=swift -R .
```

I still get the same warning, but my tags file does get updated.

What does this warning even mean and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You specified kind names for patterns like `,variable`, `,function`. However, you didn't specify kind letters, single characters representing kinds. If a kind letter is omitted, `r` is used as default; ctags handled `,variable` as `r,variable`.
When ctags read `,function`, ctags assumed the user wanted to use `r` as a kind letter for the kind named "function". However, `r` was already used for the kind named "variable". ctags warned of this conflict.

Specifying kind letters may suppress the warnings:

```
--langdef=Swift
--langmap=Swift:+.swift
--regex-swift=/(var|let)[ \t]+([^:=<]+).*$/\2/v,variable/
--regex-swift=/func[ \t]+([^\(\)<]+)\([^\(\)]*\)/\1/f,function/
--regex-swift=/class[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/c,class/
--regex-swift=/struct[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/s,struct/
--regex-swift=/protocol[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/p,protocol/
```

Universal-ctags introduced `--kinddef-<LANG>=` option.
I recommend you to use the option.

```
--langdef=Swift
--langmap=Swift:+.swift
--kinddef-Swift=v,variable,variables
--kinddef-Swift=f,function,functions
--kinddef-Swift=c,class,classes
--kinddef-Swift=s,struct,structs
--kinddef-Swift=p,protocol,protocols
--regex-swift=/(var|let)[ \t]+([^:=<]+).*$/\2/v/
--regex-swift=/func[ \t]+([^\(\)<]+)\([^\(\)]*\)/\1/f/
--regex-swift=/class[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/c/
--regex-swift=/struct[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/s/
--regex-swift=/protocol[ \t]+([^:\{<]+).*$/\1/p/
```